# Round up to nearest

Tags: javascript

If the number is 37, I would like it to round to 40, if the number is 1086, I would like it to round to 2000. If the number is 453992, I would like it to round to 500000.

I don't really know how to describe this more generally, sorry, but basically, the number in the highest place should always round up to the nearest digit, and the rest become zeros. I know how to round stuff normally, I just don't know how to cleanly deal with the variation among number of digits.

Thanks,

Edit: I deleted the 4 to 10 round, because that one seemed not to fit with the rest, and its not really necessary.

Comment: One easy google showed this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: @limelights Your "easy google" doesn't answer the question. `Math.round(37) = 37`

Comment: I believe if you read on the function for implementing rounding up to 10 is a bit further down in the examples, good sir.

Comment: What if all the numbers after the first are already 0 like 4000? Would you want it to be 5000 or stay 4000?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming all values are positive integers:

```
function roundUp(x){

    var y = Math.pow(10, x.toString().length-1);

    x = (x/y);
    x = Math.ceil(x);
    x = x*y;
    return x;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fP7Z6/*

Comment: Assuming these are all positive Integers

Comment: you can add negative numbers like this:

`function roundUp(x){
 var negative = false;
    if(x < 0) { 
        negative = true;
        x *= -1;
    }
    var y = Math.pow(10, x.toString().length-1);

    x = (x/y);
    x = Math.ceil(x);
    x = x*y;
    if(negative) x *= -1;
    return x;
}`

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following function

```
function specialRoundUp(num) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(num) / Math.LN10));
    return factor * Math.ceil(num/factor);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My *fancy* version which **works correctly with decimals and negative numbers** and correctly rounds to **nearest** power of ten as OP requested:

```
roundToNearestPow(value) {
    var digits = Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(value) + 1));
    var pow = Math.pow(10, digits - 1);

    return Math.round(value / pow) * pow;
}

// roundToNearestPow(-1499.12345) => 1000
// roundToNearestPow( 1500.12345) => 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the original number:

```
var num;
var count = num.toString().length;
```

Get first number:

```
var first = num.toString().substring(0, 1);
```

Then just ++ first and add count-1 zeros

**From Comments**

Make sure number is not a product of 10:

```
if((num % 10) != 0)
{
    //do all above in this closure
}
```

Comment: That would round 40 to 50.

Answer (score 0):

I read it like `nearest integer, which is production of an integer and some power of 10`

You can get that by

```
var myCeil = function(num){
  var power = Math.log(num,10) * Math.LOG10E;
  var head = Math.floor(power);
  var rest = power - orig;
  return Math.ceil(Math.pow(10,next))*Math.pow(10,orig);
}
i = [37, 1086, 453992];
console.log( i.map(myCeil) );
// -> [ 40, 2000, 500000 ]
```

This should work with non-integer input as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to Round to the Nearest Power of 10, try this (javascript)

```
function Round2NearestPowerOf10(x) {
    x = Math.round(x);
    var strLen = x.toString().length;
    var y = x / Math.pow(10, strLen);
    var rst = Math.pow(10, strLen - 1 + Math.round(y));
    return rst < 10 ? 10 : rst;
}
```

Result will be rounded to 10,100,1000, etc..